# generar xml servidor x

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp

tengo un proyecto en mvc  publicado en un servidor  , el proyecto se encarga en generar archivos  xml y los guarda en C:\XML\ , tengo un problema porque  lo que deseo es que se guarden los xml en la ruta de mi maquina no en la ruta del servidor , como puedo hacer que  en vez que se guarde en el servidor se guarde en mi pc con la misma ruta

Comment: Para que guerde el xml en tu maquina tiene que hacer un download del archivo generado en el servidor, el servidor NUNCA va a tener acceso a tu pc, primero por un tema fisico esta internet que lo separa, segundo por un tema de seguridad, si este podrias escribir en tu pc sin restricciones imaginete lo que podria hacer un virus o troyano

Comment: PERO PUEDO HACER QUE  AL MOMENTO DE DESCARGAR SE PUEDA GUARDAR EN UNA RUTA ESPECIFICA  O COMO PODRIA HACER QUE SE GUARDEN EN LA  CARPETA DE MI PC

Comment: la descarga va a mostrar el dialogo del browser pidiendo confirmacion del usuario donde ubicar el archivo, salvo que el que descargue sea un programa que uses por ejemplo la clase WebClient